# Keras and ImageGenerator outputs black images

Tags: keras

I'm uploading pictures from the directory using flow_from_directory. 
It is done like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                            'Dataset/train',
                            target_size=(image_rows, image_cols),
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            color_mode='grayscale',
                            class_mode='categorical',
                            classes=classes)
```

Then I'm checking loaded image like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = train_generator.next()
plt.imshow(p[0][0][:,:,0], cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Ok, but I've watched Udacity course about tensorflow and understood that it is very useful to center input data by subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation. 
So I've modified

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

to

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True,
                                   samplewise_std_normalization=True,
                                   rescale=1./255)
```

And here is the output: 
[image]

For some reason all images I'm loading are black, their numpy arrays are zeros only.

My question is:
 Why?

Comment: Two questions: 1. What is the size of your image? 2. If it is a three channel image, are all channels identical (I strongly suspect this is the case)?

Comment: Size is 64 * 160, images are grayscale and have 1 channel. Colormode in the flow_from_directory is set to 'grayscale' also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue **deleting** the rescale feature in **ImageDataGenerator**.

From:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

To:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

Comment: I did the same thing and the images are no longer black. But I want to keep the rescaling. Do you know how to fix this? And why does removing the rescaling option fix it?

Comment: @NirvanAnjirbag late you can scale after X_train = X_train / 255 and the same for X_test

Answer (score 2):

Since you set `color_mode = grayscale`, your image size will be `64 x 160 x 1` (see [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L879)). When you do sample-wise centering, it is performed along channels axis (see [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L492)). The mean matrix will be identical to the image, since the mean is being calculated along channels axis. You can test this in Python as follows:

```
img = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,5,1))
print np.squeeze(np.mean(img, axis=2, keepdims=True))  # channels last
img -= np.mean(img, axis=2, keepdims=True)
print np.squeeze(img)  # should be all zeros
```

After this you do sample-wise mean subtraction, which is nothing but dividing each pixel with a small number (`1e-7`) to avoid division by zero. This still keeps all the elements in `img` as zeros.

**What can be done to fix this?**

Instead of doing sample-wise normalization, consider doing it over the entire dataset. You can do this by setting `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization` to true.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of normalization done to the image arrays `rescale=1./255` as already mentioned. If you want to show the images you can restore the normalized images by multiplying by 255.

```
def plot_images(image_arr):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(28, 28))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    
    for img, ax in zip(image_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# single image from training set
sample_img = x_train[0] * 255    # multiply by 255 

aug_iter = image_gen.flow(sample_img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1))
aug_samples = [next(aug_iter)[0].astype(np.uint8) for i in range(10)]

plot_images(aug_samples)
```